Django sigue invocando a un proyecto anterior y da NoReverseMatch at Reverse for not found
Al correr el servidor Django invoca un proyecto que habia ejecutado anteriormente, ahora que corro mi nuevo proyecto sigue apuntando al anterior (Muestra su ruta en el navegador). He corrido nuevamente el entorno virtual, las migraciones, limpiado caché, y corrido el servidor pero no sirve.
Este es la ruta de mi proyecto anterior: localhost:8000/employees.
En el cuerpo del navegador reporta:

NoReverseMatch at /employees/ Reverse for 'department_list' not found. 'department_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name. Request Method: GET Request URL: localhost:8000/employees Django Version: 5.0.6 Exception Type: NoReverseMatch Exception Value: Reverse for 'department_list' not found. 'department_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Ese error es de el proyecto anterior.

Agradezco sus indicaciones para eliminar el rastro del proyecto anterior.

Con la información que provees no se puede reproducir tu problema pero de cualquier manera ¿ya intentaste usar docker?

ok. Este es la ruta de mi proyecto anterior:   http://localhost:8000/employees/.  y  en el cuerpo del navegador reporta:   NoReverseMatch at /employees/
Reverse for 'department_list' not found. 'department_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/employees/
Django Version:  5.0.6
Exception Type:  NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:
Reverse for 'department_list' not found. 'department_list' is not a valid view function or pattern name.
Ese error es de el proyecto anterior.

Hola Carlos, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, y agregues en ella, los datos que has agregado aqui'(y cualquier otro que sea pertinente), así evitarás que sea cerrada y/o recibir votos negativos.

hola carlos, recuerda si estas usando virtualenv debes salir del proyecto anterior y levantar el virtualenv de el proyecto que quieresz
